# Getting commit history from multiple repositories for some period

Tags: git, jenkins

I need to setup parametrized job in Jenkins, which will retrieve commit history, from multiple repos, starting from test* in their name in specific date range (will be set in jenkins parameters).
With output like:

```
testQDevices
Branch development
commit MQP-1896 somenewfeatures
Branch qa
commit MQP-1836 somenewfixes

testQAPIs
Branch development
commit MQP-1996 somenewfeatures
Branch qa
commit MQP-1939 somenewfixes
```

Can you hint me, which git command(s) can retrieve such or similar output?

UPD1. I know that I can retrieve all commits from repo, from 1 december 2015, for example, using "git log --since="2015-12-01" ". But cannot figure out, how to retrieve all logs FROM and TO (some timerange) dates. (SOLVED) Using:

```
git log --oneline --before 2018-07-1 --after 2018-06-10
```

UPD2. Additionally, can anyone hint me, how to retrieve from some organisation list of repositories, starting from "test"?

Comment: _"Can you hint me"_ what research have you done? Have you tried any commands?

Comment: I've googled, that I can: 1) retrieve all commits from repo, from 1 december 2015, for example, using "git log --since="2015-12-01" ". But cannot figure out, how to retrieve all logs FROM and TO (some timerange) dates. 2) I cannot understand, how to extract all repositories, starting from test*. Don`t get me wrong - I'm not expecting, that you will assemble all for me, but, perhaps, you can give me a right direction.

Comment: Could you update the question so your effort is more apparent to others? (I'm trying to help you question be noticed more by people)

Comment: @evolutionxbox thanks for your efforts - I will edit my question accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following :

- call [Github search API](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/) to look for repo inside your organization matching `test` in name, description or README
- parse json & filter only repo whose names start with `test`
- for each of them clone the repo from `clone_url` field
- for each directory execute `git log`

The following example use [curl](/questions/tagged/curl), [jq](/questions/tagged/jq), [xargs](/questions/tagged/xargs) & [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```bash
curl -s "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=org%3Agoogle%20test&per_page=100" | \
    jq -r '.items[] | select(.name | startswith("test")) | .clone_url' | \
    xargs -I{} git clone {}

for d in */; 
do 
    ( cd $d && \
      echo "repo ${d::-1}" && \
      echo "branch $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" && \
      git --no-pager log --oneline --before 2018-07-1 --after 2012-06-10; )
done
```